# Can I use a single address space for the GPU, CPU and FPGA look like to CUDA UVA?

Tags: c++, cuda, shared-memory, gpgpu, fpga

If I'm developing with CUDA, then I have the opportunity to use UVA (Unified Virtual Addressing) - a single address space for CPU-RAM and GPU-RAM of all GPU. Previously this was not possible, and it appeared only in version CUDA 4.0. As I understand it - it is provided by the Nvidia CUDA driver.
*[4.1. Basics of UVA CUDA Memory Management](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#basics-of-uva-cuda-memory-management)*

But if I want to use the **GPU and the [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) on a single computer connected by PCI-Express 2.0 16x** and also for them to use a single address space, is there such a possibility in FPGA similar to Nvidia UVA? What do I need to use? FPGA "UVA"? And/or will they interfere, FPGA "UVA" vs CUDA UVA?

How can I do something like this? http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/172730/20120625%20UCAA2012_Bittner_Ruf_Final.pdf

[image]

Comment: What FPGA?  You mean you have some PCI peripheral or something?

Comment: @Carl Norum Yes. I have a single computer with two GPU and one FPGA connected by PCI-Express 2.0 16x.

Comment: And can you modify whatever parts of the kernel are dealing with this UVA stuff?

Comment: @Carl Norum I don't understand what do you mean, kernel of what and for what?

Comment: For whatever system you're developing on.  The kernel is doing all this memory/address translation for the processes in question.  If you want to add another device to the mix, you'll need to get in there and incorporate it.

Comment: @Carl Norum  That is the question, are there ready FPGA-driver for this (the same as driver for CUDA to provide UVA), which will not conflict with CUDA-driver? And if it does not exist, may there have links to sample code how to do it yourself?

Comment: There are almost certainly not ready-made drivers.

Comment: @Carl Norum  Do you think there isn't ready-made driver, but is there only FPGA-RAM mapped to physical addressing of CPU-RAM, which can I map to my virtual area by using POSIX-mmap() / WinAPI-VirtualAlloc() in my programm in user-space? Need to do something like this: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/172730/20120625%20UCAA2012_Bittner_Ruf_Final.pdf

Comment: You're describing the FPGA as if it's a generic resource like a serial port.  Isn't this a question for the FPGA vendor?  CUDA doesn't offer any method to modify the behavior of a FPGA software stack.

Comment: I have voted to close this - it isn't on-topic for [SO]

Comment: I would keep the post open. The question is potentially interesting to other users. Perhaps some comments can be converted to one or more answers.

Comment: The *research.microsoft.com* link is (effectively) broken: It redirects to a generic page, *"Microsoft Research: Advancing science and technology to benefit humanity"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already found the GPUDirect RDMA [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html) which seems to answer your question.

> RDMA for GPUDirect is a feature introduced in Kepler-class GPUs and CUDA 5.0 that enables a direct path for communication between the GPU and a peer device using standard features of PCI Express.

With this, the host can initiate data movement between the GPU and a peer device. UVA means that each device has a unique part of the virtual address space, but it does not mean any arbitrary device can access the memory of another device, you still need to use the appropriate APIs.

Note that at the simplest level, all you are asking for is a single unified virtual address space. The CPU and the GPU are already unified (that's what UVA *is*), so it is entirely dependent on how your FPGA works (including its driver). The RDMA part is an optimisation for moving data between the two but the documentation is useful for UVA in general.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I convert physical FPGA-addresses into the addresses of single virtual address space (UVA), and anyone tried this transfer between the GPU <-> FPGA?

Comment: @Alex: The material you linked to in your question explains the Linux kernel API for UVA and what modification **you** will have to make to your FPGA driver to let it use RDMA with CUDA (if it is supported).

Comment: @talonmies But are RDMA (GPUDirect) and full-duplex DMA is supported only in Tesla?